# How to split the input data and load it to RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have terabytes of data to process using Apache Spark. I use the code `sparkContext.binaryFiles(folderpath)` to load all data from the folder. 
I think it loads the full data to RDD and cause OutOfMemory error.

How can I split the 1TB data to 250GBs and Let the RDD loads it?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `binaryFiles` loads every file as one entry in RDD. I assume that you have all the data in one file or just a couple of them.

Basically, you have two options:

- Split the files into smaller ones, if it is possible (the actual method depends on the data format)
- Implement [`InputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html) that understands your data format (or search for one that does it already) and correctly sets number of splits. Then, you can use [`sparkContext.hadoopFile()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#hadoopFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20int)) method to pass your input format.